# ApiController routing with non-existing parameters

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an ApiController like this:

```
SearchController : ApiController {
  public Book Get(int booksn=-1, string author="")
  {
    /* search for books matching the parameters */
  }
}
```

All parameters have default value and an empty search request returns everything.

Now my problem is that if the request contains other parameters (for example typo from the API user) it will still route to this function :

```
GET /search?booksn=3&hello=world
```

The underlying problem is that if a parameter is sent with a wrong type it will route the same way and I wont get the parameter value in the method so I can't even send an error response:

```
GET /search?booksn=helloWorld
```

Is there a way to prevent this? Either prevent wrong types, or prevent all undefined parameters?
(I have also tried with an object and the [FromUri] attribute but same problem)

Edit: I am using VS 2012 with .NET framework 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using string params even for number, using int.Parse to throw an error if the value isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
[HttpGet()]
[Route()]
public Book Get(int booksn=-1, string author="")
```

if parameters are not valid it should block the request

Comment: Thank you but attribute routing seems to be available as of VS 2013. I am using VS 2012 and .NET framework 4. I will update my question.